# Statistical relation between mutually exclusive variables

Tags: modeling, mancova

I am quite green at Statistics.Thank you so much in advace for any help you can offer.
My doubt comes from this situation:

You have a set of behavioral data, with several possible behaviors and a group of subjects, during a certain period of time. Each behavioral event lasts for at least one second. Each kind of behavior (e.g.: drinking water) is treated as a quantitative variable, so you have the frequency for each behavior for each subject in the room. My biggest problem comes from the fact that no pair of behaviors can occur at the same time, so they are not independent from each other. I would want to find out if, for example, the subjects that drink water are also the ones that talk the most.

It might be silly, but the only thing that has come to my mind is the following: first of all, dividing into two groups the subjects according to the fact they are above or below the median for quantity of "drinking water behaviors". Secondly, treating those two groups as two levels of a qualitative independent variable. Thirdly, running a MANCOVA with it, with "talking" behavior as the dependent variable and the rest of behaviors as a covariate.

**Edit suggested by kjetil b halvorsen**

**Nature and the study and design**: it’s a systematic observation study. The design is preexperimental (no control group), factorial, with inter and intra-subject measures.

**Variables**: my dependent variables (which inter-relations I want to study) are: calling the attention of the magician, getting distracted, looking at the magician, looking at a contiguous fellow student (at their left or right), looking at another student from the classroom. I want to study relations between the frequency of each behavior throughout the subjects (e.g.: are the subjects that get distracted who also look the most at contiguous fellow?)

**How the data were measured:** thanks to two cameras in a classroom with a group of Primary school children, during a spectacle performed by a magician. I have noted down several behavioral patterns. An example of my data is:
0,34,4,D
0,36,4,A
0,38,4,R
…
Being: “number of minute, number of second, number of subject, behavior”.
Meaning, in this case: “subject 4 gets distracted with something at second 34; at second 36, he/she calls the attention of the magician; at second 38, he/she looks at a partner in his/her right”.

**Sample size**: a group of 24 subjects (I am going to measure more spectacle sessions, and there will be much more subjects).

Comment: You need to tell us more about your experimental design ... which variables, how they were measured, sample size, number of participants, ...

Comment: it’s a systematic observation study. The design is preexperimental (no control group), factorial, with inter and intra-subject measures.

my dependent variables (which inter-relations I want to study) are: calling the attention of the magician, getting distracted, looking at the magician, looking at a contiguous fellow student. I want to study relations between the frequency of each behavior throughout the subjects.
I have noted down several behavioral patterns from a group (n=24). An example of a line in my data is: 0,34,4,D, neing: “minute, second,subject, behavior”.

Comment: I have the same problem though with other varriables. What kind of data analysis or charts and diagrams is appropraite or uch condition?
I think the term is mutually inclusive varriables vrsmutually exclusive varriables.